# Считает ли это мультиакком в Google Play?

Tags: google-play

Я написал несколько приложений в Android Studio разным заказчикам , через некоторое время их забанили за мультиаккаунт (Как я понял у них уже был акк который заблочили за несоблюдения правил). Сейчас хочу выложить на свой аккаунт разработчика абсолютно другое приложение(подписанное другим ключом и т.д.).Забанит ли меня Гугл?  Т.к. слышал что он отслеживает по железу (не уверен). Или лучше сделать на другой машине?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас не было проблем с аккаунтами Google вообще, то вряд-ли забанят. Смена железа не помогает, были прецеденты когда банили и на новом железе и т.д. (со мной эти случаи не связаны, ищите в интернете) Самый верный способ не забивать себе голову - это не портить отношения с Google.